# What happens to NFTs when the blockchain is forked?

Tags: nft, forks

When the blockchain underlying a cryptocurrency is forked, both the ownership status of all the currency is cloned, and everyone possesses the coins they had on the original blockchain then on both forks.

That is usually not a problem, because the value of these coins is usually "split" and quickly one of those currencies will be worth hardly anything.

But what happens with NFTs and other smart contracts on a blockchain fork? Some NFTs give you rights to some off-chain things, like e.g. they represent ownership of something.

If the chain is forked, one copy of the NFT might be sold, while the other one isn't. So the same NFT can now have multiple owners on different chains.

Has this happened before?

How is this usually handled?

What does that mean for someone owning/buying NFTs with off-chain implications?

Answer (score 1):

The authority that gives you the rights per NFT will acknowledge only one of these blockchain, probably the one that consensus says it's the leading/right one.

Just like what happened Bitcoin/Bitcoin Cash and Ethereum/Ethereum Classic - one of them will remain the one while the other will be not accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I feared, that that is going to be the answer. Because that basically invalidates the whole application of NFTs representing off-chain goods. At the time the NFT is minted, no one can foresee any forks that haven't been planned at that time. So at minting time, no contract can be made, that accurately knows, which fork will be the "real" one in the future. So, at fork-time, all parties need to agree on one fork. And if they don't, the NFT can't represent off-chain-ownership any more, because it's unclear which fork is the "correct" one... Oh my...

Comment: NFT is unique within the context of its blockchain - if blockchain duplicates, each copy is still unique within its own world. That's not really an issue, it's a fact that all exchanges managed to agree which chain is the Bitcoin chain, there's no reason this should become an issue in the future.

Comment: Let's say in the future a technology that duplicates physical matter - you'll have the same issue. Even today you have fake paintings out there, if you can't prove your asset is the original, you can have hard time selling it, or you'll sell it in a lesser value.

Comment: but it has been an issue already in the past. Have a look, for example, at Ethereum Classic. The community couldn't decide, so now we have two Ethereums. Same happened with a ton of other blockchains.

Comment: Not exactly, Ethereum Classic is something else, not Ethereum. Just like you have Solana, you don't mind that and it doesn't contradict Ethereum, we don't need one blockchain to exist to use it. In all forks, asset values retain - Bitcoin gone to 40k, Ethereum to 3k. BTW there are many more forks to Bitcoin, no one really cares..

Comment: If anything, value is **added** to new chains, value created by speculators will to bet it'll be worth something. Sometimes they profit, sometimes they lose. Dogecoin is a Bitcoin fork if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: That is the case if you are talking about pure on-chain stuff. Both cryptocurrencies and on-chain NFTs don't have a problem with being duplicated, since it's only about value (and it doesn't matter if it's split or added).

Comment: The problem I am pointing out here is off-chain stuff. Say, your NFT represents a concert ticket. Whoever owns the NFT is allowed to attend the concert. Now the blockchain spits (e.g. Ethereum vs Ethereum Classic) and now there are two NFTs. The contract doesn't specify which blockchain, since the fork wasn't foreseen at contract time. Who is now allowed to attend the concert? The one owing the Ethereum NFT, or the one owning the Ethereum Classic NFT?

Comment: The concert company will decide and let you know which one they acknowledge. The minter, in this case a physical minter is the authority to decide which is the valid blockchain, it also must validate your ownership of that NFT on that blockchain, let's say look at transaction hash in etherscan.

Comment: So if you buy an NFT you can never be completely sure if you actually bought something, because someone you don't have a contract with can decide on a whim, that your purchase was on the wrong fork? Sounds incredibly broken to me.

Comment: That's correct, but true for anything in this world. When you're buying a Picasso painting, you can never be completely sure if you actually bought something, because someone can decide on a whim, that your painting is fake.